# Server authoritative rigidbody movement in Netcode for Gameobjects Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I am having trouble with learning Netcode for Gameobjects. But I am working on a 2D space shooter multiplayer game.
My problems is that my player movement is based on a rigidbody and I can’t find anything about server authoritative rigidbody movement.

Could someone please help me?

For the normal server authoritative movement you need to use a ServerRpc
But I’m not sure if that works with a Rigidbody.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to use attach a [`ServerRigidbody`](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/advanced-topics/physics/) to the object in question. However, a `ServerRigidbody` can only accept physics forces serverside - so, how would a client move it?

The client can send their movement commands to the server (via `ServerRpc`s), which the server would then store and then use in `FixedUpdate()` to apply the movement server-side - and the outcome of these physics forces would then automatically be sent to the clients.

So, something like this should work:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class ServerPhysicsMovement: NetworkBehaviour
{

  public ServerRigidbody _rb;

  private Vector2 _inputVector;

  private float _speed = 5f;

  // ...

  [ServerRpc]
  public void AcceptMoveInputServerRpc(Vector2 moveInput)
  {
    // quickly validate and then accept input vector
    if (moveInput.sqrMagnitude > 1)
    {
      _inputVector = moveInput.normalized;
    }
    else
    {
      _inputVector = moveInput;
    }

  }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    if (IsServer)
    {
      _rb.velocity = new Vector3(_inputVector.x, 0, _inputVector.y) * _speed;
    }

  }

}
```

Don't forget to take a look at the ['Physics' section of the Netcode for GameObjects manual](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/advanced-topics/physics/) as well, as it has some more advice/things to bear in mind when using physics in your multiplayer game.